# pyspark join multiple conditon and drop both duplicate column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark from pandas.

Joining on one condition and dropping duplicate seemed to work perfectly when I do:

```
df1.join(df2, df1.col1 == df2.col1, how="left").drop(df2.col1)
```

However what if I want to join on two columns condition and drop two columns of joined df b.c. it is a duplicate.

I've tried:

```
df1.join(df2, [df1.col1 == df2.col1, df1.col2 == df2.col2, how="left").drop(df2.col1, df2.col2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [`drop`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop.html) can only take a single `Column` expression OR one/more string column names to drop. That's why it work for `drop(df2.col1)` but raises en exception when using `drop(df2.col1, df2.col2)`.

Having these two dataframes as an example:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1), (2, 2)], ["col1", "col2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(5, 3, "ok"), (2, 2, "ko")], ["col1", "col2", "status"])
```

You can drop the duplicates columns like this:

1. Using list of column names as join condition

```
df1.join(df2, ["col1", "col2"], "left").show()

#+----+----+------+
#|col1|col2|status|
#+----+----+------+
#|   1|   1|  null|
#|   2|   2|    ko|
#+----+----+------+
```

2. Using `select` expression

```
df1.join(df2, (df1["col1"] == df2["col1"]) & (df1["col2"] == df2["col2"]), "left")\
    .select(
        df1["*"],
        *[df2[c] for c in df2.columns if c not in ["col1", "col2"]]
    ).show()

#+----+----+------+
#|col1|col2|status|
#+----+----+------+
#|   1|   1|  null|
#|   2|   2|    ko|
#+----+----+------+
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Follow up quetions, if you are joining on two different named columns then #2 is only option?

Comment: @haneulkim Yes. And #2 option can also be done using aliases: `df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), ...)` then in select expr: `col("df1.*")`....